# Best Implementation to avoid if/else

Tags: c#, oop

I am doing a program for vacation in a company and the time that is allowed to be in a specific holiday.

I used an Abstract class with an abstract method :

```
public abstract class Abstract : TimeLength
{
    public AbstractTest(string employeeCode, string employee, string typeOfHoliday, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) : base(startDate, endDate, "")
    {
        TypeOfHoliday = typeOfHoliday;
        Employee = employee;
        EmployeeCode = employeeCode;
    }
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfHoliday { get; set; }

    public abstract bool HolidayValidation(string typeOfHoliday);
}
```

And I used multiple class that inherent from this abstract class like this two :

```
class MarriageVacation : Abstract
{
    public MarriageVacation(string employeeCode, string employee, string typeOfHoliday, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) : base(employeeCode, employee, typeOfHoliday, startDate, endDate)
    {
    }

    public override bool HolidayValidation(string typeOfHoliday)
    {
        if (Days() > (int)Holiday.MarriageVacation)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Marriage Vacation Can only be 5 Days");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
}


class Bereavement : Abstract
{
    public Bereavement(string employeeCode, string employee, string typeOfHoliday, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) : base(employeeCode, employee, typeOfHoliday, startDate, endDate)
    {
    }

    public override bool HolidayValidation(string typeOfHoliday)
    {
        if (Days() > (int)Holiday.Bereavement)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Bereavement Can only be 5 Days");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

I use `Enum` for holidays 
and in the `main` I want to register this based on the users choice like this :

```
List<Abstract> holiday = new List<Abstract>();
if(CmbTypeHolidays.Text == Holiday.Bereavement.ToString())
        {
            var holid = new Bereavement(CmbEmpHolidays.Text.Split('-')[0], CmbEmpHolidays.Text.Split('-')[1], CmbTypeHolidays.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(StartDateHolidays.Value), Convert.ToDateTime(EndDateHolidays.Value));

            if (holid.HolidayValidation(CmbTypeHolidays.Text))
            {
                holiday.Add(holid);
                var bindingList = new BindingList<Abstract>(holiday);
                dataGridHolidays.DataSource = bindingList;
                controlPanelHolidays.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        else if (CmbTypeHolidays.Text == Holiday.MarriageVacation.ToString())
        {
            var holid = new MarriageVacation(CmbEmpHolidays.Text.Split('-')[0], CmbEmpHolidays.Text.Split('-')[1], CmbTypeHolidays.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(StartDateHolidays.Value), Convert.ToDateTime(EndDateHolidays.Value));

            if (holid.HolidayValidation(CmbTypeHolidays.Text))
            {
                holiday.Add(holid);
                var bindingList = new BindingList<Abstract>(holiday);
                dataGridHolidays.DataSource = bindingList;
                controlPanelHolidays.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

I wanted to know a better way to implement this solution or just to change the code that inserts data to the abstract List

Comment: This question belongs to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than SO

Comment: Short answer to improve this : I would implement `HolidayValidation()` in the abstract and define a property that holds the value of the enum `Holiday`. This way, you can refactor everything in 1 place instead of duplicating your code ([DRY !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

Comment: I won't place the `MessageBox.Show` inside the classes that manage the holidays. Those classes hold logic of the application and `MessageBox.Show` belongs to the part of the application that manage the UI ([separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns))

Comment: Applying the above comment can help to simplify the method `HolidayValidation()`. -> `if (Days() > (int)Holiday.Bereavement) { return true; } else { return false; }` could then be simplified to `return Days() > (int)Holiday.Bereavement;`

Comment: In the abstract class, there are 2 strings, `EmployeeCode` and `Employee` IMHO, They hold informations about an employee and should belong to a class dedicated to employees informations, `Employee`

Comment: @Cid, we should find a way to move such questions to CodeReview, to keep SO cleaner from too indivual problems, and getting more live in CodeReview.

Comment: I do not see a need to have different classes for vacations types too. There is `TypeOfHoliday` already in the base class. It can be used for vacation validation. `if (Days() > (int)Holiday.Bereavement)` can be changed to the `if (Days() > GetVacationRestrictions(TypeOfHoliday).MaxDays)`. You can define vacation type restriction like max days, is it payed or not etc... I do not think that different kind of vacations will require different classes to be designed.

Comment: @Cid          , I Have a Class Employee but I don't know how to connect this to other classes , so i connect them with employee Code , i tried Composition but i don't know for sure that it would work like that , if i create a new holiday how to know for which employee the holiday is ?

Comment: @enis maybe [this piece of code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6EvgqM) can help you to understand how this can be done

Comment: @Cid           , Thank You , I tried this form but i have to constantly add new Employees and I can't add a holiday to them with the reference of the object ,like you did in this code. I have to make a `List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>` and than add something into it `emp.Add(new Employee(txtName.text,txtSurname.text.....))` like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this changes based on the answers on this questions this is the Main class (Abstract) :

```
public class AbstractTest : TimeLength
{
    public AbstractTest(string employeeCode, string employee, Holiday typeOfHoliday, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) : base(startDate, endDate, "")
    {
        TypeOfHoliday = typeOfHoliday;
        Employee = employee;
        EmployeeCode = employeeCode;
    }
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }
    public Holiday TypeOfHoliday { get; set; }

    public bool HolidayValidation(Holiday typeOfHoliday)
    {
        return Days() > (int)typeOfHoliday;
    }
}
```

And in the ***Main*** i changed into this :

```
Holiday MyStatus = (Holiday)Enum.Parse(typeof(Holiday), CmbTypeHolidays.Text, true);
        var holid = new AbstractTest(CmbEmpHolidays.Text.Split('-')[0], CmbEmpHolidays.Text.Split('-')[1], MyStatus, Convert.ToDateTime(StartDateHolidays.Value), Convert.ToDateTime(EndDateHolidays.Value));

        if (!holid.HolidayValidation(MyStatus))
        {
            holiday.Add(holid);
            var bindingList = new BindingList<AbstractTest>(holiday);
            dataGridHolidays.DataSource = bindingList;
            controlPanelHolidays.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"{holid.TypeOfHoliday} Cant be more than {(int)MyStatus} Days");
        }
```

For the ***typeOfHoliday*** i used ***Holiday*** type so it is easier to work with and the choice that the user makes i convert it to ***Enum Holiday***

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set up a factory that maps holiday type name to the class implementing it:

```
private class HolidayConstructorArgs {
    public string EmployeeCode {get;set;}
    public string Employee {get;set;}
    public string TypeOfHoliday {get;set;}
    public DateTime From {get;set;}
    public DateTime To {get;set;}
}

private static readonly IDictionary<string,Func<HolidayConstructorArgs,AbstractHoliday>> HolidayByTypeCode =
    new Dictionary<string,Func<HolidayConstructorArgs,AbstractHoliday>> {
        [$"{Holiday.Bereavement}"] = a => new Bereavement(a.EmployeeCode, a.Employee, a.TypeOfHoliday, a.From, a.To)
    ,   [$"{Holiday.MarriageVacation}"] = a => new MarriageVacation(a.EmployeeCode, a.Employee, a.TypeOfHoliday, a.From, a.To)
    };
```

Now you can get the factory from the dictionary, and use it to instantiate the object:

```
if (HolidayByTypeCode.TryGetValue(CmbTypeHolidays.Text, out var factory)) {
    // This is where the "magic" happens:
    // Func<> will invoke the appropriate constructor without a conditional
    var holid = factory(
        new HolidayConstructorArgs {
            EmployeeCode = CmbEmpHolidays.Text.Split('-')[0]
        ,   Employee = CmbEmpHolidays.Text.Split('-')[1]
        ,   TypeOfHoliday = CmbTypeHolidays.Text
        ,   From = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDateHolidays.Value)
        ,   To = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDateHolidays.Value)
        }
    );
    // ... The rest of your code remains the same
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the same(almost) implementation for `HolidayValidation` and you dont use `typeOfHoliday`.

From what you have posted you might as well add the Holiday enum as parameter and property to base class(`Abstract`) and not have any inheritance at all. 
Implement the `HolidayValidation` in the base class and use the Holiday property to compare to `Days`